# Replace all media (images)

Tags: plugins, theme-development

I created a new theme for my Wordpress site and I need to replace all the media (images) on the site, since I am using all new image sizes (which are larger than the largest on my current site). 98% of the images will use the same names.

Each post only contains one (featured) image and there are no images within the content area of the posts, so this makes the job slightly easier.

I was wondering what the best (and cleanest) way was to go about doing this. I have considered the following:

- Using a [Wordpress plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/enable-media-replace/)
- Manually removing the featured images from all of my posts, deleting
  them and then manually adding the new images
- Deleting all my media in my uploads folder and replacing them with
  the new images then re-generating the image sizes via [a plugin](http://wordpress.org/plugins/regenerate-thumbnails/)

I was wondering if there were any other easier and cleaner ways to do this. Most of the ways I suggested above would add downtime to my site while I get all this done.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This plugin, https://wordpress.org/plugins/enable-media-replace/ is more efficient way to replace images

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I ended up doing it all manually (it was painstaking).